# Python Dictionary with multiple keys with same name problem

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I am looking for a bit of guidance on converting information in a file to a dictionary.

**fruit.txt**

```
Apple,5
Orange,6
Pear,10
Orange,2
Apple,1
```

The output should be:

```
{'Apple': [5, 1], 'Orange': [6,2], 'Pear': [10]}
```

From my understanding, a dictionary can't hold more than one value of the same name. This was evident when the output would overwrite itself when it encountered a duplicate value. 
I tried playing around with a defaultdict but had no luck.

My next thought process was to convert it to a list and then to a dictionary using a list as the key but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Any guidance or pointers would be great.

Comment: A dictionary can have one value, a list is one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the over the lines of the file and use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to add the value to the corresponding key.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.rstrip().split(',')
        res[k].append(int(v))
```

which leads to

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Apple': [5, 1], 'Orange': [6, 2], 'Pear': [10]})
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much. 
You have no idea how much I was trying to overcomplicate this in my head. It was causing me so much frustration. I can't believe it. 

Thank you